# Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved Eclipse CDT Fedora

Tags: c++, eclipse, fedora, eclipse-cdt

Installed eclipse CDT plug-in for Fedora.

When I try to build my project it fails and says symbol cout could not be resolved.
I need to link the libraries somehow but I can't seem to get it working.

The iostream file is located in `/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream`
I go to properties, C/C++ Build, Settings,

What file path am I supposed to use in Includes?

What library search path and libraries am I supposed to include in GCC C++ Linker, Libraries

Please help I have been trying to get this simple program to work for 4-5 hours.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "test";
    return 0;

}
```

Here is the error:

```
20:28:10 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project test ****
make all 
Building target: test
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "test"  ./test.o   
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1

20:28:10 Build Finished (took 62ms)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the *complete* and *unedited* build log.

Comment: Show the error messages exactly as you see them.

Comment: I'd bet the error shows only up in eclipse (indexer problem) ...

Comment: The error you get does not match the rest of the question, and it's not something you should get if you have a proper program with a `main` function. Is it really the `test.cpp` source you show in the question?

Comment: yes it's the same program

Comment: There should be an option to rebuild the project (i.e. remove object files and rebuild them and the executable), try that (and if there are errors please update the question with that instead of the errors you have now).

Comment: "symbol cout could not be resolved" --- where does the error message say something about `cout`?

Comment: It said it when I hovered the curser over the red line. I fixed it now I think with -I/usr/include/c++